# Program that compares file sizes in two folders?

Tags: windows-xp

I'm trying to compare two folders to see which files have differing file sizes. I don't want to do a full *bit-for-bit* comparison because it would take hours to complete. I only want to compare the file sizes and see the differences.

Is there a program that does this?

Or, is there already a built-in windows command to do it?

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the specific Windows version number.  We cannot easily help you without this information.

Comment: @mdpc, I'm on SP3 for windows XP.

Comment: [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a powershell script to produce this output.  I personally use the one located here: [Treesize the Powershell Way](http://community.kaseya.com/xsp/f/28/t/16592.aspx).

It creates an interactive html page.  Since the code is provided, you can tweak it and customize it if you wish.